# Unable to where condition on a polymorphic field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause, polymorphic-associations

I have 3 models: Player, User, Bot

Player has polymorphic field named 'playerable'.
Player table looks like that:

```
id, playerable_id, playerable_type
```

When i'm trying to do:

```
Player.where(playerable: User.first)
```

I'm getting: Unknown column 'players.playerable'

It's works when i do:

```
Player.where(playerable_id: User.first.id, playerable_type: "User")
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: What does the association on your Player model look like? (the one related to playerable)

Comment: belongs_to :playerable, :polymorphic => true

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is essentially polymorphic association. This means that playerable could potentially be 2 different classes, thus rails cannot expect you to be looking for User.first when calling a polymorphic associated class.

You could do:

```
Player.where(playerable_type: => "User").first
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
has_many :players, :as => :playerable
```

in your User model, you can just do

```
User.first.players
```